# Did Diddy Kong Racing for Nintendo 64 really use 640 × 480 pixels resolution?

Tags: nintendo-64

Diddy Kong Racing for the N64 was released in late 1997. This was long before the Expansion Pak was released. I remember, and have recently re-read, an old review in a printed magazine explaining that the graphics were stunning, and that this was the first (?) N64 game to use the "high-res mode".

N64 games typically used 320 × 240 pixels, but Diddy Kong Racing allegedly used 640 × 480... without an Expansion Pak. Is this really accurate? Was it really 640 × 480? And how was it able to do this without the RAM upgrade? It looks very good, but one thing I will say, from watching streams of people playing the game on a real N64 (since I don't have a setup to actually play it myself these days, sadly) is that it looks just as blurry/fuzzy a all the other N64 games which use 320 × 240.

In short: I do not see the double resolution. It does look good, but so do all the other N64 games to me.

I suppose one possible explanation is that the capture equipment the streamers use don't fully capture the "sharpness" of 640 × 480, but that sounds unlikely. I'd assume that modern capturing devices would handle even higher resolutions from that era, such as 720p on Dreamcast.

Then again, the streamers almost always have the 4:3 picture stretched to widescreen, so if they can get *that* wrong, maybe they also get the resolution messed up somehow as well?

PS: I should add that I spent many hours trying to find technical specs but was unable to.

Comment: It's not listed here: http://www.racketboy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18266

Comment: DKR was written by Rare, right? Rare are well-known for pushing the console to its limits by bypassing a lot of Nintendo's code.

Comment: The captures on [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Diddy_Kong_Racing) are 320x240, and I don't see a reference to DKR in any of the technical references I have on N64 games.  If I come across a cartridge, I'll try to capture it from my personal N64 and verify.

Comment: I have the game, but unfortunately I don't have a working CRT television.